# How to uninstall tensorflow

Tags: uninstall

How do I find out how I installed Tensorflow (via pip or via anaconda) if I haven't any notes or recollection?
Tried pip but it doidn;t work

Comment: `history` has the last several commands you entered, it might be in there `history | grep -i tensor`? If you `sudo updatedb` (it takes a long time) then you can `locate -i tensor` and find the folders and binary and such and delete them manually; as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, sounds a bit annoying but I'll give it a try- appreciate the help nonetheless.